# How do I write nested if/then statements in haskell?

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements

I'm trying to learn haskell by writing a chess game, and gchi is complaining about one of the functions I'm trying to write (error message: "parse error on input ‘where’
"), which is supposed to check whether a candidate chess move is legal. I suspect there's something about the syntax of the if/then expressions that I'm screwing up. The function at this point of development is written as follows:

```
isLegal :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Board -> Bool
isLegal from_x from_y to_x to_y (MakeBoard board_state) =
        if (piece_at_origin == Nothing)
                then False
        
        else if (piece_at_origin == Just (Piece Pawn White))
                then 
                        if not (to_y == from_y + 1)
                                then False
                        else if (x_dist /= 1 && x_dist /= 0)
                                then False
                        else if (x_dist /= 0 && piece_at_destination == Nothing)
                                then False
 
                                        
        else
                True

        where
                piece_at_origin = board_state from_x from_y
                piece_at_destination = board_state to_x to_y 
                x_dist = abs (to_x - from_x)
                y_dist = abs (to_y - from_y)
```

When I delete the "else if" part, I don't get any problems from ghci. I'm very new to haskell so I'm sure I'm making some basic mistake here, but I would be grateful if someone could point me to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell has no statements, it has only expressions. This means that an `if …` always has a `then` and `else`, and the two subexpression (the one of the `then` and the `else` need to have the same type). This is compiled in some expression that will return the `then` part in case the condition is `True`, and the `else` part otherwise.

But what you aim to do can probably be expressed simpler with guards:

```
isLegal :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Board -> Bool
isLegal from_x from_y to_x to_y (MakeBoard board_state)
  | Nothing <- piece_at_origin = False
  | Just (Piece Pawn White) <- piece_at_origin =
      if not (to_y == from_y + 1)
        then False
        else
          if (x_dist /= 1 && x_dist /= 0)
            then False
            else
              if (x_dist /= 0 && piece_at_destination == Nothing)
                then False
                else True
  | otherwise = True
  where
    piece_at_origin = board_state from_x from_y
    piece_at_destination = board_state to_x to_y
    x_dist = abs (to_x - from_x)
    y_dist = abs (to_y - from_y)
```

In fact it might be better to work with a helper function that decides for each piece what to do:

```
isLegal :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Board -> Bool
isLegal from_x from_y to_x to_y (MakeBoard board_state)
  | Just p <- piece_at_origin = go p
  | otherwise = False
  where
    piece_at_origin = board_state from_x from_y
    piece_at_destination = board_state to_x to_y
    x_dist = abs (to_x - from_x)
    y_dist = abs (to_y - from_y)
    go (Piece Pawn White)
      | to_y /= from_y + 1 = False
      | x_dist /= 1 && x_dist /= 0 = False
      | x_dist /= 0, Nothing <- piece_at_destination = False
      | otherwise = True
    -- …
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers address cleanly what went wrong. I thought I'd also give some tips about writing concise but readable code.

First, `if x then False else y` can also be spelled `not x && y`. This observation, plus a little application of DeMorgan's laws, gets us to

```
isLegal :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Board -> Bool
isLegal from_x from_y to_x to_y (MakeBoard board_state) =
        if (piece_at_origin == Nothing)
                then False
        
        else if (piece_at_origin == Just (Piece Pawn White))
                then 
                           (to_y == from_y + 1)
                        && (x_dist == 1 || x_dist == 0)
                        && (x_dist == 0 || piece_at_destination /= Nothing)
                        && {- ... something's missing ... -}
        else
                True

        where
                piece_at_origin = board_state from_x from_y
                piece_at_destination = board_state to_x to_y 
                x_dist = abs (to_x - from_x)
                y_dist = abs (to_y - from_y)
```

Next up, the outer if-then-else structure appears to be listing all the possible cases for what piece moved. (I'm guessing the `else True` at the end is a placeholder for code you either haven't written yet or (correctly) didn't think was relevant to the question.) Exhaustive listing of cases is just what `case` is for, so let's use it.

```
isLegal :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Board -> Bool
isLegal from_x from_y to_x to_y (MakeBoard board_state) = case piece_at_origin of
    Nothing -> False
    Just (Piece Pawn White) -> (to_y == from_y + 1)
                            && (x_dist == 1 || x_dist == 0)
                            && (x_dist == 0 || piece_at_destination /= Nothing)
                            && {- ... -}
    _ -> True -- TODO
```

I personally find this code much easier to read -- the big-picture structure is much more readily apparent not just from indentation but also from syntax. As a reader, I also don't need to carefully verify that the left argument to `(==)` is `piece_at_origin` each time. Dually, as a writer, I don't need to repeat `piece_at_origin ==` in each condition.

Depending on how things progress from here, it may be useful to nest `case` expressions. For example, for many of the pieces, the legality of a move is essentially the same regardless of color -- perhaps with the exception of checking that the destination square's piece is of the opposite color (and so captured). So you might want to write something like:

```
isLegal :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Board -> Bool
isLegal from_x from_y to_x to_y (MakeBoard board_state) = case piece_at_origin of
    Nothing -> False
    Just (Piece kind color) -> case kind of
        Pawn -> (to_y == from_y + pawn_direction color)
             && (x_dist == 1 || x_dist == 0)
             && (x_dist == 0 || piece_at_destination /= Nothing)
             && {- ... -}
        Bishop -> (x_dist == y_dist)
               && {- TODO -}
        _ -> True -- TODO
```

Some of the parentheses above are not needed. I've kept them because I think they add something to the readability, but if you're super comfy with operator precedences you might choose to delete some or all of the irrelevant ones.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That's a really helpful comment. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Comment: The really tricky bits will mostly be about pawns. Most of the pieces are pretty uniform in their behavior. But pawns *can't* capture forward, and can capture either a piece on the diagonal *or* a pawn en passant. The latter situation may need to be detected both here *and* in whatever code calculates the effect of the move, and it requires knowledge of the opponent's *previous* move, which doesn't appear obviously available in the arguments as currently conceived.

Comment: @dfeuer It gets worse: checking if castling is legal requires the entire game history (or at least a suitable abstract interpretation of it).

Comment: True; I forgot about castling there. You just need two Boolean flags per player: castling allowed on king side and castling allowed on queen side. Moving a rook turns one off; moving the king turns both off. I guess that's the "suitable abstract interpretation". But I don't know that that's harder than the pawn issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` / `else` statements require **both parts** of the same type, because it is an expression which should be always evaluated to a value. And you can nest if / else expressions, in the way like: if cond1 then a else if cond2 then b else c. Note that indentations are also important in Haskell.

In you case you missed the else part in the second block.

P.S. Your code is not idiomatic Haskell, but it takes time (using guards, pattern matching).